# django rest form not valid error

Tags: django, angular, django-rest-framework

I have a model, model form and a view as follows:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def addCigar(request):
    print(request.POST)
    form = CigarForm()
    if request.POST:
        form = CigarForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cigar.save()
            cigar = Cigar.objects.filter(id=cigar.id)
            serializer = CigarSerializer(cigar, many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data)
        else:
            return Response("Form not valid, insert correct fields.")
```

Form:

```
class CigarForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Cigar
        fields = ['brand','origin','shape', 'strength', 'aroma', 'notes', 'rating', ]
```

Model:

```
class Cigar(models.Model):
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False,)
    origin = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False,)
    shape = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False,)
    strength = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False,)
    aroma = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False,)
    notes = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False,)
    rating = models.IntegerField(null=True, )
```

My angular2 frontend service:

```
public addCigar(

    brand: string, 
    origin: string,
    shape: string,
    strength: string,
    aroma: string, 
    notes: string, 
    rating: number) {

    console.log("In service")
    let obj = new CigarModel(brand, origin, shape, strength, aroma, notes, rating);

    let body = JSON.stringify(obj);
    console.log(body)

    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.post(this.myUrl + 'api/cigar/add/', body, options)
    .toPromise()
    .then(response => response.json())
}
```

This however gives me form not valid error. The print statement in the view prints `<QueryDict: {}>`  and console.log in service body prints `{"brand":"Nitish","origin":"India","shape":"Thin","strength":"Strong","aroma":"Wood","notes":"Good","rating":"4"}`

What am I doing wrong here? Is problem with my frontend or backend?

UPDATE: Instead request.POST I am now using request.data

Comment: All example I saw about body, for angular 2 are like this : var body = 'username=myusername&password=mypassword'; Try to transform your json string into this string. param1=value_param1&param2=value_param2  etc

Comment: Is there any function or parameter to convert it like this? Instead of JSON.stringyfy()?

Comment: All your import are good ? For Headers ?

Comment: Can you just print(request) in your addCigar function and show us the result

Comment: That's what my sent request is from browser console:{"brand":"Nitish","origin":"Spain","shape":"Thin","strength":"Strong","aroma":"Wood","notes":"Good","rating":"4"}. Print(request.data) in django view gives me {u'origin': u'India', u'rating': u'4', u'strength': u'Strong', u'brand': u'Nitish', u'aroma': u'Wood', u'shape': u'Thin', u'notes': u'Good'}

Comment: How do you mean please? I am not sure how I should write it

Comment: I wrote a new reply :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [this example](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/#writing-regular-django-views-using-our-serializer)

**Create a class JSONResponse**

```
class JSONResponse(HttpResponse):
    """
    An HttpResponse that renders its content into JSON.
    """
    def __init__(self, data, **kwargs):
        content = JSONRenderer().render(data)
        kwargs['content_type'] = 'application/json'
        super(JSONResponse, self).__init__(content, **kwargs)
```

You don't need to init a form to validate your data. It's json content. You need to use your serializer.

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def addCigar(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = CigarSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JSONResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
        return JSONResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

Comment: Is the function is part of that class? Or is it separate? Or is it data=request.data?

Comment: Alright, it's working. I had to change it to data=request.data. Could you please explain why this JSONResponse? Because in DRF Response is by default JSON, right?

Comment: This subclass return only JSON data. Response method of DRF is not by default JSON. You need to define `content_type`. [See the arguments here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/responses) You can use Reponse, but you need to define more parameter with your data. (headers, status, content_type.) Glad to help you